# Tapestry: When should a Session State Object be preferred to a Session Attribute?

Tags: session, session-variables, session-state, tapestry

From the [Tapestry doc](http://tapestry.apache.org/session-storage.html) I seem to understand that a field annotated with `@SessionAttribute` and a field annotated with `@SessionState` work in the same way, except that `@SessionAttribute` stores the value by name (and the name can be specified), which means that different instances of the same class can be stored, while `@SessionState` stores the value by type so storing different instances of the same class will not work, the new instance will always overwrite the old one (even if the two are different fields with different name and from different classes).

So it seems that `@SessionState` doesn't offer any advantage over `@SessionAttribute`, only limitations, but I'm probably missing something. I'm not able to figure out any case where using `@SessionState` could be more advisable than `@SessionAttribute` for any reason.

Are there such cases ?

Answer (score 0):

@SessionAttribute is largely intended for some interop cases, where some other, non-Tapestry code (another servlet) is expecting the data to be stored using an explicitly specified name.

@SessionState's advantage is that the name is automatically determined from the type ... one less thing to care about, and more amenable to refactoring.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question.
Does the fact that `@SessionAttribute` is largely intended for some interop cases mean that there might be disadvantages in using it instead of `@SessionState` in standard, non-interop cases (in addition to having to care about setting the name) ? Like performance, memory use or other ?

Comment: I have been asked to make a case for `@SessionState` concrete advantages over `@SessionAttribute` and I couldn't mention any, plus I was unable to counter the objection that `@SessionState` automatically determining the name from the type is as much of an advantage as it is a limitation, depending on the usage context, because that supposed advantage is also the cause of the impossibility to store more than one instance. Actually at least for now I have to agree with that objection.